# List all times in the day at a half hour rate

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, sequence

Shortest answer wins.

It must be sorted, and in 24hr time. The final line does not have a comma.

Output should be as follows:

```
'00:00',
'00:30',
'01:00',
'01:30',
'02:00',
'02:30',
'03:00',
'03:30',
'04:00',
'04:30',
'05:00',
'05:30',
'06:00',
'06:30',
'07:00',
'07:30',
'08:00',
'08:30',
'09:00',
'09:30',
'10:00',
'10:30',
'11:00',
'11:30',
'12:00',
'12:30',
'13:00',
'13:30',
'14:00',
'14:30',
'15:00',
'15:30',
'16:00',
'16:30',
'17:00',
'17:30',
'18:00',
'18:30',
'19:00',
'19:30',
'20:00',
'20:30',
'21:00',
'21:30',
'22:00',
'22:30',
'23:00',
'23:30'
```

Comment: Is this 24 hour time? Could you please provide the entire output?

Comment: Must the output be sorted?

Comment: Yes. It must be sorted, and in 24hr time. Sorry will update.

Comment: Does the final line have a comma?

Comment: Final line does not have a comma :)

Comment: Can we use a double quote instead of single ?

Comment: What if it takes my program 23.5 hours to run?

Comment: I can't see why that would be a negative.

Comment: @tfitzger I had a go at doing that - it was 40+ more chars!

Comment: what about daylight saving, leap seconds etc?

Comment: Just a small suggestion about upvotes. I try to upvote every valid answer to a challenge I create as a small reward for taking the effort. I have plenty of rep and don't really need an upvote here, but please consider other answerers who may give up responding if their answers are ignored after lots of hard thinking and debugging.

Comment: Taking a next step: there is an emoji for each time at a half hour rate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
Pjbm%"'%02d:%s0',"d*U24"03
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Pjbm%25%22%27%2502d%3A%25s0%27%2C%22d*U24%2203&debug=0)

We start with the cartesian product of `range(24)` (`U24`) with the string `"03"`.

Then, we map these values to the appropriate string formating substitution (`m%"'%02d:%s0',"d`).

Then, the resultant strings are joined on the newline character (`jb`).

Finally, we remove the trailing comma (`P`) and print.

Comment: Looks like we have a new contender for the prize. Author of pyth, that's almost cheating ;)

Answer (score 15):

## Befunge-93, 63 bytes

```
0>"'",:2/:55+/.55+%.":",:2%3*v
 ^,+55,","<_@#-*86:+1,"'".0. <
```

[image: animation]
<sup>*(animation made with [BefunExec](https://github.com/Mikescher/BefunExec))*</sup>

Answer (score 14):

## Bash: <s>58</s> <s>47</s> 46 characters

```bash
h=`echo \'{00..23}:{0,3}0\'`
echo "${h// /,
}"
```

Comment: I like this solution :)

Comment: Anonymous user suggested `echo \'{00..23}:{0,3}0\'|sed 's/ /,\n/g'` of 40 characters. Nice. Thanks. But I prefer to make use of `bash`'s own strength.

Comment: `printf "'%s',\n" {00..23}:{0,3}0`

Comment: @manatwork oh i didn't read the question well, sorry...

Comment: `printf "'%s'\n" {00..23}:{0,3}0|sed $\!s/$/,/`  is 45 bytes

Comment: Or even 44 if you include a literal line break in the format string instead of `\n`. Nice, but I prefer my `bash` solutions to be pure `bash` as possible.

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, <s>31 30</s> 29 bytes

```
24,[U3]m*"'%02d:%d0',
"fe%~7<
```

This is pretty straight forward using printf formatting:

```
24,                              e# get the array 0..23
   [U3]                          e# put array [0 3] on stack
       m*                        e# do a cartesian product between 0..23 and [0 3] array
                                 e# now we have tuples like [[0 0], [0 3] ... ] etc
         "'%02d:%d0',
"fe%                             e# this is standard printf formatting. What we do here is
                                 e# is that we format each tuple on this string
    ~7<                          e# unwrap and remove comma and new line from last line
                                 e# by taking only first 7 characters
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=24%2C%5BU3%5Dm*%22%27%2502d%3A%25d0%27%2C%0A%22fe%25%7E7%3C)

Comment: Looks like this is going to take the gold. We'll give it until tomorrow ;)

Comment: @EspenSchulstad I wish it would actually give me some gold. *sigh*

Comment: Remember, it's not only viritual gold, but also honor. What we do in life echoes in eternity.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```py
for i in range(48):print"'%02d:%s0',"[:57-i]%(i/2,i%2*3)
```

Like [sentiao's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49742/21487) but using a `for` loop, with slicing to remove the comma. Thanks to @grc for knocking off two bytes.

Comment: Would this work: `"'%02d:%s0',"[:57-i]`

Comment: @grc Ahaha of course, that's much better

Comment: Better than I could do!

Answer (score 6):

## Java - 119 bytes

I started with Java 8's StringJoiner, but that means including an import statement, so I decided to do it the old way:

```
void f(){String s="";for(int i=0;i<24;)s+=s.format(",\n'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'",i,i++);System.out.print(s.substring(2));}
```

Perhaps this can be improved by getting rid of the multiple occuring `String` and `System` keywords.

Comment: a version in groovy perhaps :)

Comment: You can shorten this to 159: Remove the space before `a`, move the `i` increment, lose the `for` braces, and move the comma/newline to the beginning (which lets you use the shorter `substring` and get rid of `length()`). Since functions are allowed by default, you can get make it even shorter by eliminating boilerplate: `void f(){String s="";for(int i=0;i<24;)s+=String.format(",\n'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'",i,i++);System.out.print(s.substring(2));}` Even a bit more if you make it just return the string instead of printing it, but that seems to go against the spirit, if not the letter.

Comment: Damn, that's brilliant! I got to keep those tricks in mind, thanks!

Comment: Oh, another few: change `String.format` to `s.format`. Your compiler/IDE may complain about it, but it works ;)

Comment: Nice one! format's a static method, so it _should_ be accessed by its class, but indeed, using it this way also works!

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>94</s> <s>61</s> <s>56</s> 51

```
$><<(0..47).map{|i|"'%02d:%02d'"%[i/2,i%2*30]}*",
"
```

Thanks to @blutorange (again) for his help in golfing!

Comment: You can reduce that to 61 bytes: `puts (0..47).to_a.map{|h|"'%02d:%02d'"%[h/2,h%2*30]}.join","` (there's a newline after the last comma)

Comment: Thank you again! I really didn't try it much...

Comment: Ruby needs some love. 58 bytes ;) `puts Array.new(48){|i|"'%02d:%02d'"%[i/2,i%2*30]}.join','`

Comment: @blutorange @rcrmn you can reduce 4 more bytes (and get to my solution below :)) ) by replacing `.join` with `*` :)

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>52</s> <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 45B

```
$,=",
";say map<\\'$_:{0,3}0\\'>,"00".."23"
```

With help from ThisSuitIsBlackNot :)

Answer (score 4):

### JAVA <s>95</s> 94 bytes

I love the fact that printf exists in Java:

```
void p(){for(int i=0;i<24;)System.out.printf("'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'%c\n", i,i++,(i<24)?44:0);}
```

Ungolfed

```
void p(){
    for(int i=0;i<24;)
        System.out.printf("'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'%c\n", i,i++,(i<24)?44:0);
}
```

EDIT
Replaced the `','` with `44`

Comment: 24.times{printf("'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'%c\n",it,it,(it<24)?44:0)}​ in groovy :) same solution, just that it's down to 65 chr

Comment: @EspenSchulstad Would that be considered a standalone function, or is there other boilerplate that would be needed to get it to run?

Comment: If you have groovy, you could either run that in groovysh or just as a groovy script in a .groovy-file. then you don't need no function.

Comment: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/24001

Comment: @EspenSchulstad Interesting. I've only done minimal work with Groovy.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

I golfed something in python but it turned out to be exactly the same as Sp3000's answer. So I decided to give Pyth a try:

```
V48<%"'%02d:%d0',",/N2*3%N2-54N
```

It's a exact translation of Sp3000 answer:

```
for i in range(48):print"'%02d:%d0',"[:57-i]%(i/2,i%2*3)
```

It's my first go at Pyth, so please do enlighten me about that 1 byte saving.

Comment: Nicely done, and welcome to Pyth.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
puts (0..23).map{|h|"'#{h}:00',
'#{h}:30'"}.join",
"
```

Comment: You can reduce 3 bytes by changing `\n` to actual newlines and removing the space between `join` and `"`. On the other hand, take note that the specified output has leading zeros for the hours.

Comment: Also, some more bytes by changing `puts ` to `$><<` (without space) and `.join` with `*`. You still have the leading zero problem for the hours, though.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 109 bytes

```
foreach(new DatePeriod("R47/2015-05-07T00:00:00Z/PT30M")as$d)$a[]=$d->format("'H:i'");echo implode(",\n",$a);
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>116</s>,<s>115</s>,<s>101</s>,<s>100</s>,<s>95</s>,<s>74</s>,<s>73</s>, 71

May be able to scrape a few more bytes off this...

```
main(a){for(;++a<50;)printf("'%02d:%d0'%s",a/2-1,a%2*3,a<49?",\n":"");}
```

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by creating a function rather than a complete program. Just replace "main" with "f", or whatever your favourite letter is.

Comment: Oh thats a very nice suggestion.....one I always forget!

Comment: Suggest `a/49*2+",\n"` instead of `a<49?",\n":""`

Comment: It's from  3 years ago - I'm not updating it.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, <s>319</s> <s>307</s> 305 bytes

```
WITH t AS(SELECT t.f FROM(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4))t(f)),i AS(SELECT i=row_number()OVER(ORDER BY u.f,v.f)-1FROM t u CROSS APPLY t v),h AS(SELECT i,h=right('0'+cast(i AS VARCHAR(2)),2)FROM i WHERE i<24)SELECT''''+h+':'+m+CASE WHEN i=23AND m='30'THEN''ELSE','END FROM(VALUES('00'),('30'))m(m) CROSS APPLY h
```

Un-golfed version:

```
WITH
t AS(
    SELECT
        t.f
    FROM(VALUES
         (0),(1),(2),(3),(4)
    )t(f)
),
i AS(
    SELECT
        i = row_number() OVER(ORDER BY u.f,v.f) - 1
    FROM t u 
    CROSS APPLY t v
),
h AS(
    SELECT
        i,
        h = right('0'+cast(i AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
    FROM i
    WHERE i<24
)
SELECT
    '''' + h + ':' + m + CASE WHEN i=23 AND m='30' 
                              THEN '' 
                              ELSE ',' 
                         END
FROM(
    VALUES('00'),('30')
)m(m)
CROSS APPLY h
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 34 bytes

```
j+\,bmjk[\'?kgd20Z/d2\:*3%d2Z\')48
```

This can definitely be improved.

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B%5C%2Cbmjk%5B%5C%27%3Fkgd20Z%2Fd2%5C%3A*3%25d2Z%5C%27)48&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
     m                          48   map each d in [0, 1, ..., 47] to:
        [                      )       create a list with the elements:
         \'                              "'"
           ?kgd20Z                       "" if d >= 20 else 0
                  /d2                    d / 2
                     \:                  ":"
                       *3%d2             3 * (d%2)
                            Z            0
                             \'          "'"
      jk                               join by "", the list gets converted into a string
j+\,b                                join all times by "," + "\n"
```

Comment: Always impressive with these golfing languages :) I do somehow appreciate it more when it's done in a non-golfing language.  Does anyone know if there is a golf-jar-lib to java for instance?

Comment: Obligatory port of [sentiao's](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49742/21487) gives 31: `j+\,bm%"'%02d:%s0'",/d2*3%d2 48` with string formatting

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 74 bytes

Updated for Swift 2/3...and with new string interpolation...

```
for x in 0...47{print("'\(x<20 ?"0":"")\(x/2):\(x%2*3)0'\(x<47 ?",":"")")}
```

Comment: The final line is specified to *not* have a comma & your code prints it.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 69 bytes

```
print',\n'.join(["'%02d:%s0'"%(h,m)for h in range(24)for m in'03'])
```

Quite obvious, but here's an explanation:

- using double-for-loop
- alternating between `'0'` and `'3'` in string format is shorter than a list
- `%02d` does the padding for `h`
- `m`doesn't need padding as the alternating character is on a fixed position
- `'\n'.join()` solves the final-line requirements

<strike>I have no idea if it can be done shorter (in Python 2).</strike>

**by Sp3000, 61 bytes :**
`print',\n'.join("'%02d:%s0'"%(h/2,h%2*3)for h in range(48))`

Comment: How about: `print',\n'.join("'%02d:%s0'"%(h/2,h%2*3)for h in range(48))`

Comment: Brilliant, Sp3000! (you should post it)

Comment: Nah, not different enough to post in my book. All I did was drop the square brackets (which are unnecessary even in your one) and drop `m`. (Also it's 59 bytes, not 61)

Answer (score 2):

## [golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/) <s>52</s> 51 chars

```
~@n=0,47w(S.q("'%02d:%d0'%c",n/2,n%2*3,n<47&44|0))$
```

Using ascii 44 = `,` and 0 a space saves a character.

An ungolfed Lua version would be

```
for h=0,47 do
   print(string.format("'%02d:%d0'%c",h/2,h%2*3, if h<47 and 44 or 0))
end
```

The `if` statement is much like the ternary operator `a > b ? 44 : 0`.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia: <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 61 characters

```julia
[@printf("'%02d:%d0'%s
",i/2.01,i%2*3,i<47?",":"")for i=0:47]
```

#### Julia: 64 characters

(Kept here to show Julia's nice `for` syntax.)

```julia
print(join([@sprintf("'%02d:%d0'",h,m*3)for m=0:1,h=0:23],",
"))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>60 58</s> 64 bytes

```python
for i in range(24):print("'%02d:00,\n%02d:30'"%(i,i)+', '[i>22])
```

Ungolfed:

```python
for i in range(24):
    if i <23:
        print( ('0'+str(i))[-2:] + ':00,\n' + str(i) + ':30,')
    else:
        print( ('0'+str(i))[-2:] + ':00,\n' + str(i) + ':30')
```

Try it online [here](http://repl.it/nBQ/5).

Comment: Why not put it on 1 line, and save another 2 bytes.

Comment: I don't think this works - no leading zero on the hour.

Comment: @isaacg fixed that!

Comment: The output is not the same as in the original question.

Comment: @sentiao what is different?

Comment: you can save a couple of bytes by mixing single and double quotes instead of escaping your quotes `'\'%02d:00,\n%02d:30\''` could be `"'%02d:00,\n%02d:30'"` saving 2 bytes for the slashes

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 85 bytes

```
putStr$init$init$unlines$take 48['\'':w:x:':':y:"0',"|w<-"012",x<-['0'..'9'],y<-"03"]
```

Unfortunately `printf` requires a 19 byte `import`, so I cannot use it.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <strike>77</strike> 86+1 bytes

Didn't realize there had to be quotes on each line (+1 is for `-p` flag with node):

```
"'"+Array.from(Array(48),(d,i)=>(i>19?"":"0")+~~(i/2)+":"+3*(i&1)+0).join("',\n'")+"'"
```

old solution:

```
Array.from(Array(48),(d,i)=>~~(i/2).toFixed(2)+":"+3*(i&1)+"0").join(",\n")
```

ungolfed version (using a for loop instead of `Array.from`):

```
var a = [];
// there are 48 different times (00:00 to 23:30)
for (var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    a[i] =
        (i > 19 ? "" : "0") +
            // just a ternary to decide whether to pad
            // with a zero (19/2 is 9.5, so it's the last padded number)
        ~~(i/2) +
            // we want 0 to 24, not 0 to 48
        ":" +  // they all then have a colon
        3*(i&1) +
            // if i is odd, it should print 30; otherwise, print 0
        "0" // followed by the last 0
}
console.log(a.join(",\n"));
```

Comment: 72: `Array.from(Array(48),(d,i)=>\`'${i>19?"":0}${0|i/2}:${i%2*3}0'\`).join\`,\n\``. Replace \n with an actual newline.

Answer (score 2):

## Fortran 96

```
do i=0,46;print'(a1,i2.2,a,i2.2,a2)',"'",i/2,":",mod(i,2)*30,"',";enddo;print'(a)',"'23:30'";end
```

Standard abuse of types & requirement only for the final `end` for compiling. Sadly, due to implicit formatting, the `'(a)'` in the final `print` statement is required. Still, better than the C and C++ answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

## C# - 120 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){for(var i=0;i<24;i++)System.Console.Write("'{0:00}:00',\n'{0:00}:30'{1}\n",i,i==23?"":",");}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## , 39 chars / 67 bytes (non-competing)

```
↺;Ḁ⧺<Ḱ;)ᵖ`'⦃Ḁ<Ḕ?0:⬯}⦃0|Ḁ/2}:⦃Ḁ%2*3}0',”
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E2%86%BA%3B%E1%B8%80%E2%A7%BA%3C%E1%B8%B0%3B%29%E1%B5%96%60%27%E2%A6%83%E1%B8%80%3C%E1%B8%94%3F0%3A%E2%AC%AF%7D%E2%A6%830%7C%E1%B8%80%2F2%7D%3A%E2%A6%83%E1%B8%80%252*3%7D0%27%2C%E2%80%9D)</kbd>

*Not a single alphabetical character in sight...*

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <strike>69 70</strike> 62 bytes

```php
for($x=-1;++$x<47;)printf("'%02d:%d0',
",$x/2,$x%2*3)?>'23:30'
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/j44mV)

Outputting `'23:30'` at the end is a bit lame, and so is closing the php context using `?>` without opening or re-opening it. An cleaner alternative (but 65 bytes) would be:

```php
for($x=-1;++$x<48;)printf("%s'%02d:%d0'",$x?",
":'',$x/2,$x%2*3);
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/JfJ3C)

Thank you @Dennis for the tips. Alternative inspired by the contribution of @ismael-miguel.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Your code prints a null byte at the end. I'm not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you, you're right... I assumed PHP would see it as end-of-string. Posted a new version.

Comment: `<?...?>'23:30'` saves three bytes. Also, you can replace `\n` with an actual newline.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>74</s> 65 bytes

We generate a 2 line string for each hour, using text formatting:

```python
print',\n'.join("'%02u:00',\n'%02u:30'"%(h,h)for h in range(24))
```

This code is fairly clear, but the clever indexing and integer maths in the answer by Sp3000 gives a shorter solution.

Comment: no reason to use formatting for 00 and 30, save 9 bytes with `"'%02u:00',\n'%02u:30'"%(h,h)`

Comment: you could save some bytes by having too loops :    `print',\n'.join("'%02u:%02u'"%(h,i)for h in range(24)for i in[0,30])`

Comment: Thanks DenDenDo. I used this to save some bytes. Dieter, I can see where your idea may help, but I could save more bytes with that idea from DenDenDo.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 89 bytes

```js
for(i=a=[];i<24;)a.push((x="'"+("0"+i++).slice(-2))+":00'",x+":30'");alert(a.join(",\n"))
```

Comment: Quick question: how many arguments [`Array.push()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7) supports? ;)

Comment: You're right. That is a polyad. Thanks, I'll make that change after I finish testing my entry for another challenge.

Comment: A few more characters can be removed with some elementary reorganizations: `for(i=a=[];i<24;)a.push((x=("0"+i++).slice(-2))+":00",x+":30");alert(a.join(",\n"))`

Comment: There, I fixed it.

Comment: That reuse of variable x is quite ugly coding habit. If you change the loop control variable to something else (as in my suggestion at 2015-05-07 15:28:25Z), then you can add the opening single quotes to x's value to reduce the two `"'"+` pieces to one: `for(i=a=[];i<24;)a.push((x="'"+("0"+i++).slice(-2))+":00'",x+":30'");alert(a.join(",\n"))`

Comment: That one's giving me a syntax error for some reason:  "Invalid character '\u8203'"

Comment: No idea what kind of crappy character keeps infiltrating in that text. If you type in the `alert()`'s parameter by hand, the rest of code should be fine.

Comment: @manatwork Just asked google, unicode 8203 is a zero-width space, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2: 64 bytes

```
print ',\n'.join(['%02d:00,\n%02d:30'%(h,h) for h in range(24)])
```

Comment: The output is not the same as in the original question.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the edit I made.  here is the correct version also 64 chars: `print',\n'.join("'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'"%(h,h)for h in range(24))`

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby - 52 bytes**

```
puts (0..47).map{|i|"'%02d:%02d'"%[i/2,i%2*30]}*",
"
```

Comment: This seems like my solution with just the change of the `.join` for `*`... It's common courtesy to instead of just posting a new answer with a minor improvement, to suggest the improvement to the original poster. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-should-the-policy-on-improving-or-incorperating-other-peoples-solutions-be

Comment: @rcrmn I agree I made a mistake and I apologize for it - should've had looked for other ruby answers first. Great work though in your answer with `$><<`!

Comment: Don't worry about it, you are new here: I was advising you so that you could avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```
<?for($i=0;$i<24;$i++){$a=sprintf("%02d",$i);echo"'$a:00',\n'$a:30'",$i<23?",\n":'';}
```

I tried but it isn't the shortest in PHP.

Old code:

```
<?for($i=0;$i<24;$i++){($i<10?$a="0$i":$a=$i);echo"'$a:00',\n'$a:30'".($i==23?'':",\n");}
```

Comment: Why the parenthesis around the whole first ternary expression? And reverse the last ternary to use the shorter `<` operator instead of `==`: `$i<23?",\n":''`.

Comment: @manatwork So it adds the 0 in front of every number lower than 10, without the parenthesis it wouldn't work. With the < it would add a comma at the end

Comment: Works for me. But anyway, you are using the ternary in a strange way. Usually the assignment is done outside. And that expression could also be rewritten to compare against 9 instead of 10, sparing another 1 character: `<?php for($i=0;$i<24;$i++){$a=$i>9?$i:"0$i";echo"'$a:00',\n'$a:30'".($i<23?",\n":'');}`

Comment: Ah yes, I had it the other way around. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing: the parenthesis around the last (now only) ternary is required just because you concatenate it to the other piece of string. As `echo` supports multiple parameters, just enumerate them separated with comma and you can spare the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 69 Bytes

```
$d=date 0;(0..47|%{"'{0:HH:mm}'"-f$d;$d=$d.AddMinutes(30)})-join",`n"
```

I love how it's shorter to *use actual date functions* than simply try to brute force the numbers with `.ToString` operators to pad zeroes and logic to decide if we're in a `00` or a `30` output.

Sets a new date `$d` to be `00:00:00 Jan 1 0000`, then goes into a loop 48 times with `0..47|%{..}`. Each time in the loop we generate our output using the `-f` operator. The `HH:mm` format for dates gives us 24-hour time with minutes, just as we want. Then, we `addMinutes(30)` to prep us for the next go-round. Outside the loop, we `-join` everything together with a comma and a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [TreeHugger](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Treehugger), 1433 Bytes

TreeHugger is a bf variant that uses a binary tree instead of a linear tape. Read about it [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Treehugger) and you can run scripts on the implementation [here](http://codepen.io/AndoDaan/full/yyaxJP). As for how this program works, here is a rough run down:

- **Store** the characters needed

  - In the first loop, get within 5 of the desired value
  - Manually adjust to the correct value
- **Walk** through the tree and print the proper characters in the proper order

  - *WARNING:* This step is a little tedious

```java
++++++++++[>++++++>+++++>+++++>++++>++++>+^^^^^<+++++>+++++^^^<++++>+++++>+++++^<+++++^^<+++++>+++++>++++++^<++++++^^<+++++>++++++^<+++++^^^^-]>-->+>-->->++++>^^^^^<+++>++^^^<->->+++^<++^^<-->+>---^<----^^<>-----^<++++^^^^<.<..^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<..^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.^>.^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.^>.^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.<.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.<.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.>.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.>.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.^><.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.^><.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.^>>.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.^>>.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.<<.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.<<.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.<>.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.<>.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.><.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.><.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.>>.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<.>>.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<.^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<.^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>..^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>..^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<<.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<<.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<>.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<>.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.<.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.<.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.>.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.>.^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<<<.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<<<.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<<>.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<<>.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<><.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<><.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<>>.^^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.>.^<>>.^^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<.^.^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<.^.^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<.^^>.^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<.^^>.^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<..^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<..^^^>[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<.^>.^^^>.>>.[.>]^^^^^^^^<.<<.^>.^^^>.>.>.>.
```

---

### Un-Golfed

The three digit numbers are the ASCII values we're aiming for in the approximation and adjustment phases. The numbers in the print phase, indicate the hour that we are printing.

```py
# Approximation
+++++ +++++ [
058 > +++++ +
051 > +++++
048 > +++++
039 > ++++
044 > ++++
010 > +
^^^^^ 
053 < +++++ 
052 > +++++
^^^
039 < ++++
049 > +++++
053 > +++++
^
052 < +++++
^^
048 < +++++
051 > +++++
057 > +++++ +
^
056 < +++++ + 
^^
050 < +++++ 
055 > +++++ +
^
054 < +++++
^^^^ -
]
# Adjustment
058 > --
051 > +
048 > --
039 > -
044 > ++++
010 >
^^^^^ 
053 < +++ 
052 > ++
^^^
039 < -
049 > -
053 > +++
^
052 < ++
^^
048 < --
051 > +
057 > ---
^
056 < ----
^^
050 < 
055 > -----
^
054 < ++++ 
^^^^
# Print
0
<.<..^^     >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<..^^     >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
1
<.<.^>.^^   >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.^>.^^   >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
2
<.<.<.^^^   >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.<.^^^   >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
3
<.<.>.^^^   >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.>.^^^   >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
4
<.<.^><.^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.^><.^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
5
<.<.^>>.^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.^>>.^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
6
<.<.<<.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.<<.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
7
<.<.<>.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.<>.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
8
<.<.><.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.><.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
9
<.<.>>.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<.>>.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
10
<.>.^<.^^   >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<.^^   >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
11
<.>..^^     >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>..^^     >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
12
<.>.^<<.^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<<.^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
13
<.>.^<>.^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<>.^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
14
<.>.<.^^^   >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.<.^^^   >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
15
<.>.>.^^^   >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.>.^^^   >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
16
<.>.^<<<.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<<<.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
17
<.>.^<<>.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<<>.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
18
<.>.^<><.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<><.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
19
<.>.^<>>.^^^^ >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.>.^<>>.^^^^ >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
20
<.<<.^.^^      >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<<.^.^^      >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
21
<.<<.^^>.^^  >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<<.^^>.^^  >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
22
<.<<..^^^    >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<<..^^^    >[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
23
<.<<.^>.^^^    >.>>.[.>] ^^^^^ ^^^
<.<<.^>.^^^    >.>.>.>.
```

This can be golfed down more, I have a `1198 byte` version that should work, but I think this implementation might have a bug. So stay tuned until I finish debugging my own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 93 bytes

```Java
void t(){for(int i=0;i<24;)System.out.printf("'%02d:00',\n'%02d:30'%s",i,i,i++<23?",\n":"");}
```

**Ungolfed**

```Java
void t()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("'%02d:00',\n", i);
        System.out.printf(   "'%02d:30'", i);
        System.out.printf( i < 23 ?",\n":"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 127 bytes

I'm not a very good golfer :s

```js
var r='',i,m=":00',\n",q="'"
for(i=0;i<23;i++){
h=("0"+i).slice(-2)
r+=q+h+m+q+h+":30',\n"
}
r+=q+i+m+q+i+":30'"
console.log(r)
```

## Java, 179 bytes

```
public class M{public static void main(String[] a){String r="",f="'%02d:%s',\n";for(int i=0;i<24;i++)r+=String.format(f+f,i,"00",i,"30");System.out.print(r.replaceAll(".$",""));}}
```

ungolfed

```
public class M {
    public static void main(final String[] a) {
        String r = "", f = "'%02d:%s',\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)r += String.format(f + f, i, "00", i, "30");
        System.out.print(r.replaceAll(".$", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: don't be that modest! :)

Comment: I'm not super good with javascript but I [made a couple of improvements](http://ix.io/ilS) to bring it down to 104 bytes :) I removed some whitespace and moved the 23:** hour into the loop. This means you don't need the `r+=q+i+m+q+i+":30'"` line, but there is an extra comma, so you have to cut it off when you print it. That lets you save a lot of bytes, both from the removed line and variable initialization. You also might want to look into making this a 0-arg function, so you can use ES6 function syntax. There's a bit of boilerplate code you have to add, but usually returning > printing.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ - 104 bytes

I spend a while trying to find an obtuse way to remove the comma, but in the end the simple approach seemed to be by far the most efficient.

```
#include<cstdio>
int main(int c,char**v){for(c=-1;c++<47;printf("'%.2d:%d0'%s\n",c/2,c%2*3,c>46?"":","));}
```

I shouldn't need to initialize c to -1 but I couldn't get an inline postfix increment to work how I expected.

Comment: You can reduce one byte by `#include<cstdio>`. Also, one byte can go from the `c=-1` by changing it to `c=0` and moving the increment inside the printf like `for(c=0;48>c;printf("'%.2d:%d0'%s\n",c/2,c%2*3,c++>46?"":","));`. Note that with this, the actual output may depend on the compiler, the processor, etc, because of the unsequenced modification of c, and the compiler will give a warning accordingly.

Comment: @rcrmn Thanks! Unfortunately, that for loop is what I had initially, but it doesn't behave as I would expect on MSVC++.  Your code gives me 00:30 to 24:00, which indicates right-to-left argument evaluation, but if I move the `++` into `c/2` I get the 00s and 30s swapped, which would indicate left-to-right evaluation.  My guess is the compiler is attempting to optimize by doing `c++/2` first and using the result to calculate `c%2`.

Comment: Oh I see. Using Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) here. I thought I was using gnu g++, but it seems apple likes to hide these things to the user.

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzcxM08jM69EIVmzOi2/SMM6WVdX28TcOj4@qTQzpyQzL76gCCidpqGkrqpnlGKlmmKgrlock6eko5usbwQkVI20jHWUdJSAXBNzTU3r2v//AQ "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>81</s> 77 bytes

Template strings work well for cutting down the size.

```
alert([...Array(48)].map((x,i)=>`'${i<20?0:''}${i/2|0}:${i%2*3}0'`).join`,
`)
```

Comment: Usually we call such code ECMAScript to emphasize the presence of experimental features. By the way, your code generates no output. (In [JavaScript Standards for IO](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/803/javascript-standards-for-io) meta discussion we concluded that JavaScript should also use explicit output methods when output is requested.)

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for that link! I figured there would be something like that, but couldn't find anything, and having seen other examples elsewhere on the site without explicit prints, I just went with it. I'll update the answer. Good to know on the ECMAScript detail as well! =)

Comment: I don't think this works: http://www.es6fiddle.net/i9essmvf/

Comment: @royhowie For some reason, es6fiddle requires variables be declared with var (add it before the i=0 and you'll see it works). While usually a good idea to have, it is not required.

Comment: It certainly works as is in Firefox. And 1 more character can be spared thanks to the template strings: instead of `\n` in `join()`'s parameter, make that string also a template string and include a literal newline.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <del>82</del> 77 bytes

Nothing fancy, just abusing PHP's string capacities.

```php
<?for($H=-1;$H++<23;)echo$H?",
'":"'",$H=str_pad($H,2,0,0),":00',
'$H:30'";
```

Probably there's something that I can cut off.

### Old version, 82 bytes:

```php
<?foreach(range(0,23)as$H)echo$H?",
'":"'",$H=str_pad($H,2,0,0),":00',
'$H:30'";
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# - lots (but give away free with windows)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write(String.Join(",\n", Enumerable.Range(0, 48).Select(i => "'" + i / 2 + ":" + (i % 2) * 3 + "0'")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL: 97 characters

```postgresql
select string_agg(to_char(x*interval'30m','''hh24:mi'''),','||chr(10))from generate_series(0,47)x
```

#### PostgreSQL: <s>132</s> <s>131</s> 116 characters

Kept here to show PostgreSQL's cool way to generate timestamp series.

```postgresql
select string_agg(to_char(x,'''hh24:mi'''),','||chr(10))from generate_series('150511','150511 23:59',interval'.5h')x
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 145 bytes

```
import time as t;i=48;a=t.asctime;w=3600;s=t.sleep;s(24-int(a()[11:13])*w+w-60*int(a()[14:16]));
while i:print '\''+a()[11:16]+'\',';i-=1;s(w)
```

I guess the code is fairly readable (altough quite long). Once you run the program it waits until actual local time is `00:00h`, then prints the time and waits for 30 min, time in which the program prints the hour again. It keeps repeating this process until `00:00h` of the next day is reached. Therefore, with lots of patience and no incidents that force your computer to shutdown all the times get printed.

Answer (score 0):

### Ceylon, 101 bytes

```
shared void run(){print(",\n".join{for(h in 0..23)for(m in[0,3])"'``"``h``".pad(2,'0')``:``m``0'"});}
```

Formatted:

```
shared void run() {
    // original:
    print(",\n".join {
            for (h in 0..23)
                for (m in [0, 3])
                    "'``"``h``".pad(2, '0')``:``m``0'"
        });
}
```

This uses an iterable comprehension with two for-clauses, and nested string templates. ``` "``h``" ``` is a shorter way of writing `h.string` (we can't pad an integer directly).
`",\n".join(iterable)` puts the commas and new-lines between the strings (this way we can avoid the `,` in the last line).

Unfortunately Ceylon has no `printf` functionality, which would certainly make things shorter (no `.pad` or `.string` necessary).

After finding that "straightforward" solution, I experimented with some variations, which unfortunately result in slightly longer shrinked solutions:

```
shared void run() {
    print(",\n".join(
            (0..23)
                *.string
                *.pad(2, '0')
                .map((x) => "'``x``:00',\n'``x``:30'")
        ));
}
```

(102 bytes)

```
shared void run() {
    print(",\n".join {
            for (h in 0..23)
                let (x = "``h``".pad(2, '0'))
                    "'``x``:00',\n'``x``:30'"
        });
}
```

(104 bytes)

```
shared void run() {
    print(",\n".join(
            (0..23)
                .map((i) => "``i``".pad(2, '0'))
                .map((x) => "'``x``:00',\n'``x``:30'")));
}
```

(111 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque, 30 bytes

Burlesque is sadly rather weak when it comes to formatting because it doesn't have a `printf` (yet).

```
23rzm{2'0lp}":00 :30"wdcp)\[uN
```

Details see [here](http://md.mroman.ch/blog/2015-11-13.html).

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 24 bytes

```
V24V2%"'%02d:%d0',",N*3H
```

[Run code](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V24V2%25%22%27%2502d%3A%25d0%27%2C%22%2CN%2A3H&debug=1)

```
V24                     for loop 0-23, N counter
  V2                    for loop 0-1, H counter
    %                   format string
      "'%02d:%d0',"     source string
      ,                 begin list tuple
        N               first element, hour
        *3H             second element, minutes
```

Every second iteration of the second for loop, `H` is 1, which toggles the minutes digit between 0 and 3.

Interpreted code generated by the debugger:

```
for N in num_to_range(24):
 for H in num_to_range(2):
  imp_print(mod("'%02d:%d0',",[N,times(3,H)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>104</s> 96 bytes

```
for($h=$m=0;$h<24;){echo($h||$m?",\n":"")."'".($h<10?0:"")."$h:".($m*3)."0'";if($m)$h++;$m=!$m;}
```

**exploded view**

```
for ($h = $m = 0; $h < 24; ) {
  echo ($h || $m ? ",\n" : "") . "'" . // echoes ",\n" on all but the first loop
       ($h < 10 ? 0 : "") . "$h:" .    // leading 0 for 0:00 - 9:30
       ($m * 3) . "0'";                // :00 if $m=0, :30 if $m=1
  if ($m) $h++;                        // increments $h if :30
  $m = !$m;                            // swaps :00 <-> :30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 88 bytes

```
void c(){for(int i=0;i<48;)System.out.printf("'%02d:%s0'%s",i/2,i%2*3,i++<47?",\n":"");}
```

Shorter than the other three Java answers: [93 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81145/52210) & [94 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49752/52210) & [119 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49737/52210)

**Explanation:**

```
void c(){                  // Method
  for(int i=0;i<48;)       //  Loop from 0 to 48 (exclusive)
    System.out.printf(     //   Print with format:
      "'%02d:%s0'%s",      //    "'##:#0'X" (where `#` is a digit, and `X` is a String)
      i/2,                 //    (%02d) Current index divided by 2 and automatically floored
      i%2 * 3              //    (%s0) i%2 is either 0 or 1 (multiplied by 3 is either 0 or 3)
      i++<47 ? ",\n" : ""  //    (%s) A comma and new-line, unless it's the final line
                           //  End of loop
}                          // End of method
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#Lc7fCoIwGAXwe5/iYzDccpiYUDijJ@jKy@pi@Sc@UCduBiE@@5rR3YED53eqThkD1yUAMFZZrMC9NdZQMb60emI4WMBzIrHITpKXH2ObPtazjcfJVy0jIU3SOqcmCakhAvepQJruDgKjqMiOFyLuA8kJ4XJ1AOP87Dzxl35Qr3BgpfVrr9sDFN@ewMZLH9ZgdV8)

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 96 bytes

```
t=20000101000000
Loop,48{
FormatTime,i,%t%,HH:mm
Send,'%i%',`n
EnvAdd,t,30,Minutes
}
Send,{BS 2}
```

AHK does not play nicely with time values so I have to store two variables: one to track the time in the format `YYYYMMDDHH24MISS` and another just to store the pretty text in the format `HH:MI`.